# Is it legal for a webshop to charge credit card in different currency than what is shown?

Tags: european-union, consumer-protection, spain, credit-card

Consider a webshop based in Spain (European union). After the buyer selects their country (shipping address) the prices are shown in the local currency, and only in that. However during payment, the credit card is actually charged in euros which are then converted to the local currency by the buyer's bank, using their own exchange rate. As such, you typically pay more than what is shown (at the moment it is a 3% difference). Also it makes comparing prices hard and gives them an unfair advantage. If the price is shown in my local currency I expect to pay that much. If the price is shown in euros, I know to apply my bank's rates and fees.

TL;DR: if they charge in euros, must they show the price in euros?

Comment: As a practical matter, the legal system may not be a good way to address this issue. Say you make a 100 Euro purchase and thought it would be the equivalent of 97 Euros. For a 3 Euro difference, a complaint to the customer service and a bad review  at the website or on social media or a review website probably makes more sense than trying to enforce the law whatever it may be. You might try disputing the charge via your credit card.

Comment: I think that this is the credit card company's end.  You can elect which currency the transaction happens in, they then do the conversions.  So the seller may not know the price in Euros.  They just want to be paid in Euros.

Comment: A store must tell you what the price is before you can agree to the contract, whether that is implicit by handing over money, or a clearly defined button in a webstore. That is such a basic thing, I don't evne know which law that is. If the website says "60 malzones" when you press "Buy Now", it better charge *exactly* "60 malzones", not any other amount in any other currency. Now, if you incur extra charges because your account is not in "malzones", that is your problem and your fee to pay, but if they charge something else, that's wrong on a very basic level.

Comment: A note to the Americans that might read this: in Europe, we value being properly informed about our contracts. If a pricetag says 0.99€, you go to the checkout and pay 0.99€. Not 0.99€ plus an amount of taxes nobody is willing to calculate beforehand. That would be... well, not fraud, but certainly illegal, probably misleading advertisement. So being told you have to pax X and then being charged anything but  *exactly* X to the cent is a major dealbreaker here.

Comment: Who is charging the extra money? Are they giving a reason why? A company can't charge more than they say for the product (although they can add fees for some purposes, most obviously shipping). And your credit card company can add what it likes in the way of fees (assuming you have signed a contract with them and they've made the fee schedule available in some way).

Comment: The point is, the price is shown in local currency so I expect no conversion fees. Instead they convert that to some euros using their own non-public exchange rate and then charge that to the credit card. This has two problems: one, the exchange rate is different from the one actually used by the bank and two, the bank may require a fee. I don't even know what euro amount they will try to charge when I pay.